# android how to do channel/program/bank change to use sampled midi file

Tags: android, midi

I'm using the android/midi-lib for my app, but need to get some better sounds for the metronome and possibly the drum.  eventually I also need to be able to access the sounds of the drumset.  Does anybody know how I can get the midi channels/etc to point to a sample(.mp3 file or something) in my res/raw or assets directory instead of being forced to use the sounds in the standard midi library?